# Wiki pages completely blank after migration to SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2013

We recently migrated our SharePoint 2010 site to 2013, and ALL of the wiki pages brought over are completely blank. Source looks like:

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]-->
</head>
```

I suspect this is due to the fact that the layout for 2010 wiki pages come with webpart zones while 2013 has none.

Has anyone encountered this issue and been able to successfully migrate/repair 2010 to 2013 Wiki pages?

Comment: I've come across this problem too and it is a big issue for us.  Even using Metalogix to copy the pages across doesn't solve the issue completely.  Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 there is only one webpart per wiki page, which is hidden. It doesn't have multiple webparts as it was in SharePoint 2010. The hidden webpart in SharePoint 2013 for wiki pages has a Wiki field which can be easily edited and can contain markup which will make the webparts from the hidden zone appear inline in the content (as divs).

I am not sure what could be the exact reason behind loosing complete code while migrating it from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. Even we faced lots of issues while migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013, out of which few are still unresolved.

What I can suggest you at this point of time, if the content is still available to you of the wiki pages from the old SharePoint site, then better you re-create the wiki pages in SharePoint 2013 using markups, scripts etc, if required. It will help you to get things in place.

Migration in SharePoint was really a hard time for us. I wish you all the best. I hope my suggestion would help you to find a work around.

Comment: Don't know that this is true in all cases - in our migrations, currently suffering heavily from this problem, the wikipages can certainly contain web parts.  It is possible for me to rebuild the wikipages exactly as they were prior to migration, including webparts in the same layout as in 2010.

We are using Sharepoint 2010 compatibility view mode for all the sites however, we aren't running a visual upgrade, which likely makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

We also got blank pages after performing site upgrade from 2010 to 2013 version.

In my case had to deactivate the publishing features and removed the VariationRootPageLayout.aspx file.

I used a powershell script to deactivated the publishing features and logs the url with the features name as a csv file.

After that I performed update-spsite and reactivated the publishing features.